# Implementing column generation in SAS

Tags: column-generation, dantzig-wolfe-decomposition

I am currently trying to implement [this model](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11608/how-to-modify-master-problem-and-individual-sub-problems-in-column-generation/11620?noredirect=1#comment25135_11620) in SAS. Unfortunately, I always get this error. How can I solve this and finally get the final roster $x$ and the total value of $slack_{ts}$ (preferably in an Excel list)?

This is the code:

```
  /* declare sets and parameters */
   set ISET, TSET, SSET;
   num demand {TSET, SSET};

   /* read input data here */
    set ISET = {1, 2, 3};
    set SSET = {1, 2, 3};
    set TSET = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    num demand{TSET, SSET} = {(1, 1): 2, (1, 2): 1, (1, 3): 0, (2, 1): 1, (2, 2): 2, (2, 3): 0, (3, 1): 1, (3, 2): 1, (3, 3): 1,
               (4, 1): 1, (4, 2): 2, (4, 3): 0, (5, 1): 2, (5, 2): 0, (5, 3): 1, (6, 1): 1, (6, 2): 1, (6, 3): 1,
               (7, 1): 0, (7, 2): 3, (7, 3): 0};
    /* Generate random values for alpha */
    execute INIT_RANDOM(123); /* Set a seed for reproducibility */
    alpha{i in ISET, t in TSET} = rand("Uniform", 0, 1);
               

   /* declare decision variables */
   var motivation {ISET, TSET, SSET} >= 0 <= 1;
   var slack {TSET, SSET} >= 0;
   var mood {ISET, TSET} >= 0 <= 1;
   var x {ISET, TSET, SSET} binary;

   /* declare objective */
   minimize z = sum {t in TSET, s in SSET} slack[t,s];

   /* declare constraints */
   con SatisfyDemand {t in TSET, s in SSET}:
      sum {i in ISET} motivation[i,t,s] + slack[t,s] = demand[t,s];

   con Indicator {i in ISET, t in TSET, s in SSET}:
      x[i,t,s] = 1 implies motivation[i,t,s] = mood[i,t]
   suffixes=(block=i);

   con MotivationImpliesX {i in ISET, t in TSET, s in SSET}:
      motivation[i,t,s] <= x[i,t,s]
   suffixes=(block=i);

   con AlphaMood {i in ISET, t in TSET}:
      alpha * sum {s in SSET} x[i,t,s] + mood[i,t] = 1
   suffixes=(block=i);

   /* call MILP solver with Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition algorithm */
   solve with milp / decomp;

   /* write output data here */
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is correct SAS code.  You need only one SOLVE statement, but I provided three for illustration.  You can also read from data sets by using the READ DATA statement.

```
proc optmodel;
   /* declare sets and parameters */
   set ISET = 1..3, TSET = 1..3, SSET = 1..7;
   num demand{TSET, SSET} = [
      2, 1, 0,
      1, 2, 0,
      1, 1, 1,
      1, 2, 0,
      2, 0, 1,
      1, 1, 1,
      0, 3, 0
   ];
   /* Generate random values for alpha */
   call streaminit(123); /* Set a seed for reproducibility */
   num alpha{ISET, TSET};
   for {i in ISET, t in TSET} alpha[i,t] = rand("Uniform", 0, 1);
               
   /* declare decision variables */
   var motivation {ISET, TSET, SSET} >= 0 <= 1;
   var slack {TSET, SSET} >= 0;
   var mood {ISET, TSET} >= 0 <= 1;
   var x {ISET, TSET, SSET} binary;

   /* declare objective */
   minimize z = sum {t in TSET, s in SSET} slack[t,s];

   /* declare constraints */
   con SatisfyDemand {t in TSET, s in SSET}:
      sum {i in ISET} motivation[i,t,s] + slack[t,s] = demand[t,s];

   con Indicator {i in ISET, t in TSET, s in SSET}:
      x[i,t,s] = 1 implies motivation[i,t,s] = mood[i,t]
   suffixes=(block=i);

   con MotivationImpliesX {i in ISET, t in TSET, s in SSET}:
      motivation[i,t,s] <= x[i,t,s]
   suffixes=(block=i);

   con AlphaMood {i in ISET, t in TSET}:
      alpha[i,t] * sum {s in SSET} x[i,t,s] + mood[i,t] = 1
   suffixes=(block=i);

   /* call MILP solver with (default) branch-and-cut algorithm */
   solve;

   /* call MILP solver with Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition algorithm and connected components as blocks */
   solve with milp / decomp=(method=concomp);

   /* call MILP solver with Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition algorithm and user-defined blocks */
   solve with milp / decomp;

   /* write output data */
   create data SolutionData_its from [i t s] x;
   create data SolutionData_ts from [t s] slack;
quit;

proc export data=SolutionData_its dbms=xlsx
   outfile="myoutfile1.xlsx"
   replace;
run;

proc export data=SolutionData_ts dbms=xlsx
   outfile="myoutfile2.xlsx"
   replace;
run;
```