Adding additional coordinating constraint to a decomposed model
As suggested by @RobPratt, here is the new opened question. I have these decomposed master and subproblems:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_t \sum_s \text{slack}_{ts} \\
&\text{subject to} &\sum_i \sum_r \text{motivation}_{its}^r \lambda_{ir} + \text{slack}_{ts} & = \text{demand}_{ts} &&\forall t,s &&\\
&&\sum_r \lambda_{ir} &= 1 &&\forall i &&\\
&&\lambda_{ir} &\in\mathbb{Z}^+ &&\forall i,r\\
&&\text{slack}_{ts} &\ge 0 &&\forall t,s
\end{align}
and subproblems($i$):
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &0-\sum_{t,s} \pi_{ts} \text{motivation}_{its} - \mu_i \\
&\text{subject to} &-M(1-x_{its}) \le \text{motivation}_{its} - \text{mood}_{it} &\le M(1-x_{its}) &&\forall t,s \\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\le x_{its} && \forall t,s \\\
&&\alpha_{it} \sum_s x_{its} + \text{mood}_{it} &= 1 &&\forall t\\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\in[0,1] &&\forall t,s \\
&&\text{mood}_{it} &\in[0,1] &&\forall t \\
&&x_{its}&\in \{0,1\} &&\forall t,s\\
\end{align}
Now i want to additionally impose the constraint:
$$\sum_i x_{its} \geq 1 \quad \forall t, s$$
One approach would be to add a new single problem that includes all $i$
and impose the new constraint there. How would that look like?

Your original compact problem is:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_t \sum_s \text{slack}_{ts} \\
&\text{subject to} &\sum_i \text{motivation}_{its} + \text{slack}_{ts} &= \text{demand}_{ts} &&\forall t,s \\
&&-M(1-x_{its}) \le \text{motivation}_{its} - \text{mood}_{it} &\le M(1-x_{its}) &&\forall i,t,s \\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\le x_{its} && \forall i,t,s \\
&&\alpha_{it} \sum_s x_{its} + \text{mood}_{it} &= 1 &&\forall i,t\\
&&\sum_i x_{its} &\ge 1 &&\forall t,s\\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\in[0,1] &&\forall i,t,s \\
&&\text{slack}_{ts} &\ge 0 &&\forall t,s \\
&&\text{mood}_{it} &\in[0,1] &&\forall i,t \\
&&x_{its}&\in \{0,1\} &&\forall i,t,s\\
\end{align}
For the Dantzig-Wolfe reformulation, introduce $\lambda_r \ge 0$ and substitute $\text{motivation}_{its} = \sum_r \text{motivation}_{its}^r \lambda_r$ in the (objective and) complicating constraints to obtain the master problem:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &\sum_t \sum_s \text{slack}_{ts} \\
&\text{subject to} &\sum_i \sum_r \text{motivation}_{its}^r \lambda_r + \text{slack}_{ts} & = \text{demand}_{ts} &&\forall t,s &&\text(\text{$\pi_{ts}$ free})\\
&&\sum_r \lambda_r &= 1 &&&&\text{($\mu$ free)}\\
&&\lambda_r &\in\mathbb{Z}^+ &&\forall r\\
&&\text{slack}_{ts} &\ge 0 &&\forall t,s
\end{align}
The reduced cost of $\lambda_r$ is $0-\sum_{i,t,s} \pi_{ts} \text{motivation}_{its}^r - \mu$,
so the subproblem is:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &0-\sum_{i,t,s} \pi_{ts} \text{motivation}_{its} - \mu \\
&\text{subject to} &-M(1-x_{its}) \le \text{motivation}_{its} - \text{mood}_{it} &\le M(1-x_{its}) &&\forall i,t,s \\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\le x_{its} && \forall i,t,s \\\
&&\alpha_{it} \sum_s x_{its} + \text{mood}_{it} &= 1 &&\forall i,t\\
&&\sum_i x_{its} &\ge 1 &&\forall t,s\\
&&\text{motivation}_{its} &\in[0,1] &&\forall i,t,s \\
&&\text{mood}_{it} &\in[0,1] &&\forall i,t \\
&&x_{its}&\in \{0,1\} &&\forall i,t,s\\
\end{align}

Isn't there a separate subproblem for each $i$? If so, how can you sum over $i$ in a subproblem?

@prubin Yes, decomposing by $i$ is the more natural approach.  But in another comment the OP asked for details about instead putting the new constraints in a single subproblem that includes all $i$: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11608/how-to-modify-master-problem-and-individual-sub-problems-in-column-generation/11620?noredirect=1#comment25933_11620

So is your answer above replacing the various subproblems by a single one? This version of the question still mentions "subproblems($i$)".

Yes, after imposing the new constraints, the subproblems are no longer independent and instead form a single block.
