How to decompose a specific constraint in the sub-problem?
Suppose there is a specific constraint as follows to impose the precedence relation between the tasks:
$$ \sum_{m \in M} m.x_{j,m} \leq \sum_{m \in M} m.x_{k,m} \quad \forall (j,k) \in T $$
I want to decompose this specific constraint based on each $m \in M$ and would like to know how can I bring this out in the sub-problem? I have tried the following, but I am unsure if it really imposes what the relation would be.
$$ x_{j} \leq x_{k} \quad \forall (i,j) \in T $$

Is $x$ binary?  Do you also have $\sum_m x_{jm}=1$ for all $j$?

Dear @RobPratt, yes. Actually the master is a set partitioning. The precedence and the rest of the constraint are in the sub.

You have a linking constraint across $m$.  You can impose any relaxation of it into subproblem $m$, but $x_{jm} \le x_{km}$ is not a relaxation.

Dear @RobPratt, I am unsure if I understand your idea. Do you mean is $x_j \leq x_k$ cannot be a block in the sub problem m?

Yes, that constraint is too strong.  It would enforce that if task $j$ is assigned to machine $m$ then task $k$ must also be assigned to that same machine $m$ rather than just some $m'$ with $m' \ge m$.

Thanks. Do you have any idea on how can I bring the precedence out in the sub? I really do not want to keep that in the master?

Also, what about you idea regarding $\sum_m m.x_{j,m} = w_j \quad \forall j$. then impose $w_j \leq w_k$, where $w$ is a non- negative variable? Does it have the same restrictions?

Precedence is fundamentally a constraint that involves more than one $m$.  Instead of decomposing by machines, you could decompose by clusters of tasks.  Then any precedences that involve tasks in the same cluster can be imposed in the corresponding subproblem.

Your idea about $w_j$ and $w_k$ then involves linking variables that cannot appear in different subproblems.

Dear @RobPratt, thanks. Your idea about clustering the tasks is interesting. Do you have any resources to more digging?

@RobPratt, suppose I want to keep the precedence in the master and besides the set partitioning. As the machines are identical we can aggregate the $\sum_{m} \sum_{p} \lambda_{m}^p$ into $\sum_{p} \lambda_{}^p$. Then the constraint would be again as the form of $\sum_{p} a_{j}^p \lambda_{}^p - \sum_{p} a_{k}^p \lambda_{}^p \leq 0 \quad \forall (j,k) \in T$. Would you say, that what I am trying to convexify the constraint is correct?

To convexify, you want to replace each $x_{jm}$ with $\sum_p x_{jm}^p \lambda_m^p$, yielding precedence constraint
$$\sum_m \sum_p x_{jm}^p \lambda_m^p \le \sum_m \sum_p x_{km}^p \lambda_m^p,$$ and you cannot use $\lambda^p = \sum_m \lambda_m^p$ here.

Thanks @RobPratt. Please, let me think more about that and I will get back to you.

Dear @RobPratt, I have some additional questions. 1) Is not it necessary to apply the index $j$ on both sides of the above constraint? 2) I tried to compute the pricing term regarding the above constraint as, $$ \sum_{(j,k) \in T} \sigma_{jk}.(x_j - x_k),$$ where $\sigma$ is the dual variables of the precedence constraint, But I am unsure if I stand on the right way!

I recommend writing out your full compact formulation, explicitly defining which constraints belong to which blocks, replacing each variable with a convex combination in terms of $\lambda$, and finally writing out the reduced cost of $\lambda$, which will become your subproblem objective.  See https://or.stackexchange.com/a/11620/500
